# Access a function in a plugin from another plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have some functions in another plugin that I'd like to use. For example, I'm using the shortcodes plugin, and it has a function shortcode_atts that I want to use in my plugin.

Answer (score 4):

If the method you want to access is public and in another service file, you could access it via the service layer:

```
craft()->theOtherPluginService->method();
```

The method you are using above, the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) should work fine without declaring the \Craft namespace, as the plugins should already be loaded into the Craft namespace.  It's used for accessing static and constant methods:

```
ClassName::method()
```

In cases where you may be loading a library that is not in the Craft namespace, the syntax you're using above would be needed, where you declare the full namespace:

```
\SomeOtherNameSpace\ClassName::method()
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, Ben! I did see the way you're showing above. However, I actually think using `use \Craft\Whatever as Mything` below the namespace declaration is a working and clean way of doing it. Then you can just `Mything::method()`

Comment: Sounds good Ryan. I realize I was using `PluginName::method()` in my first example instead of the appropriate `ClassName::method()` (updated above). I agree that when necessary using the `use` operator below the namespace is cleaner than the full namespace in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

`\Craft\Shortcode::shortcode_atts()`

Seems directly accessing it via **namespace** would be correct (assuming!)